# Return the names of heroes that begin with I or J, and all their mentors NOSQL

Tags: regex, mongodb, nosql

In this exercise that my professor refuses to correct in class, I have to do this query:

Return the names of heroes that begin with I or J, and all their mentors.

Here is the structure of the objects I'm playing with :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63495a11d935f6aa5139ee33"
  },
  "name": "Medea",
  "faits": "Quete de la toison d'or avec les argonautes",
  "ascendants": [
    "Eson",
    "Eole"
  ],
  "gender": "female",
  "mentor": "Chipute"
}
```

And here is my attempt at making it work:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {$project : {{$name :{{ $substr : {$name, 0,1}}: {$or:[ {$eq: 'I'},{$eq: 'J'}]}}  },$mentor: 1}}
]
)
```

And here is te Error returned to me:

```
Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
    at Object.serialize (node:v8:332:7)
    at u (C:\Users\achop\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.33.1\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@mongosh\node-runtime-worker-thread\dist\worker-runtime.js:1917:594983)
    at postMessage (C:\Users\achop\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.33.1\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@mongosh\node-runtime-worker-thread\dist\worker-runtime.js:1917:595591)
    at i (C:\Users\achop\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.33.1\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@mongosh\node-runtime-worker-thread\dist\worker-runtime.js:1917:600488)
```

Thank you for your time, there may be numerous mistakes.

Comment: Yeah I suspect there are a few different things going on here.  The `Error: clone` message here is about incorrect syntax trying to run the operation in the shell embedded in Compass.  I suggest starting with a small query and building up. In terms of getting the results that you want, check into using regex for the `find` (or `$match` if you want to use aggregation) part and then separately apply the projection for `mentor` (either as the second argument for `find` or as a second stage of `$project` to the agg pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can use this query:

It's a simple `find` query where you can use [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to find the documents where `name` starts with (`^`) I or (`|`) J.

Also option `i` is to do the query case insensitive, you can delete that line if you only want values that starts with capital letters.

And the second object in the query is the [projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection). Which is used to output the values you want. In this case only `name` and `mentor`.

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    $regex: "^(I|J)",
    $options: "i"
  }
},
{
  name: 1,
  mentor: 1
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DhXSii7eCcB)